# Hibernate/JPA querying embeddable property of a joined subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities: ShoppingCart, abstract class User and EndUser that extends User. AddressDetails is an embedable that is embeded into EndUser entity.

My query looks like this: `SELECT sc FROM ShoppingCart sc JOIN sc.endUser as endUser WHERE endUser.name EQ someName and endUser.addressDetails.zip EQ 1234`

When I remove the second part of the WHERE clause, and leave just the endUser.name part, everything works fine (name is a property of endUser entity class which is a subclass of User entity class). 
However, when I try the whole query I get:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: zip of:
```

ShoppingCart:

```
@Entity
public class ShoppingCart {

   ...

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable
   private EndUser endUser;
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
public abstract class User {
...
}
```

EndUser:

```
@Entity
public class EndUser extends User {
   ...
   @Column
   private String name;

   @Embeded
   private AddressDetails addressDetails;
   ...
}
```

Address Details:

```
@Embeddable
public class AddressDetails {
   ...
   private int zip;
   ...
}
```

Comment: no typos in getter/setter/query?

Comment: I checked and there were no typos anywhere. I actually found the solution. Check my Answer

Comment: `@Embeded` is a typo

Comment: Yes it is, but I've written this code on the post manually. There was no typo in my actual code. Thanks for pointing that out though

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the problem.

When I change FetchType to EAGER on @ManyToOne reladtionship between ShoppingCart and endUser the query works.

So it should be:

```
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable
   private EndUser endUser;
```